# Adding SSL certificate to the front end of my site

Tags: ssl

I ask my host company to add wildcard SSL certificate to my WordPress site, which was done but it wasn't showing the green padlock icon so I laid a complaint and they were able to put it up, but it seems only the backend of the site that is secured because that's where the green padlock icon is showing. When I asked my host company why, they said I might have some unsecured things like images on my site.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please don't use capital letters for the title.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-ssl/ and https://wordpress.org/plugins/http-https-remover/ This ensures that if I go to an http page I get redirected to https and that everything like images is requested over HTTPS.